# fscanf copies a line from file twice in C

Tags: c

```
                while(1<2) {
                    nscan=fscanf(infile, "%s %s %d%c",temp.name, temp.surname,&temp.code,&termch);
                    if(nscan==EOF) break;
                    if(nscan!=4 || termch!='\n')
                        printf("Error\n");
                    RecBSTInsert(&a,temp);

             }
```

for some reason nscan //if(nscan==EOF) break; does not get executed when it is supposed to and it runs one more time giving the binary tree one more value, which is same with the last one.

Comment: Aside, FYI, instead of "1<2" it is most common to do "true" instead.

Comment: true is not defined in C. Just do while(1).

Comment: A better test, though not a complete solution, is `while (!feof(infile))`.  At least this explains to the human *why* it is looping.

Comment: wallyk i have tried this but still same problem

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer i tried this but didnt work. I also think that fscanf ignores whitespaces on its own.

Comment: `true` certainly is defined in C if you `#include <stdbool.h>`.

Comment: @MahonriMoriancumer `"%s %s %d%c"` and `" %s %s %d%c"` is not different.  Specifiers `"%s"` and `"%d"` consume leading white-space on their own without the need for a leading `" "` in the format.  Note: `"%c"`, `"%n"`, `"%[]"` doe not consume leading white-space.

Comment: @chux, you are correct. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @OP What _type_ is `nscan`?  It should be `int`.

Comment: @OP Recommend to not use `while (!feof(infile))`.  The file data given in your below comment, belongs in the post.

Comment: @OP With your latest edit, the post does not make sense. `if(nscan==EOF) break;` is nowhere to be found.  Strongly suspect your problem it that what your are experiencing and what your posted, either the  original and current do not match.

Comment: @OP `"Bill Person ,1 Bob Dog ,2 Andrew Cat ,3"` does not show where the file's end-of-lines exist.  Post the file code is using.

Comment: i just changed the the way to stop the loop. I am trying to find a way not to pass the last entry of the file twice. This code is working but if i remove the `printf("%d",i);` and `i++` for some weird reason the last entry passes twice again

Comment: @OP You have change more than "just changed the the way to stop the loop".  You need to post the structure declaration, the data being scanned, declaration of variables and includes.

Comment: I hope a mod rolls back his edits. You aren't supposed to edit in a solution.

Comment: Appending to a post or making minor grammar/indentation is good to do for a post. but a @aglasser says, undo the edit change, append to your post if needed.

Comment: In your original post code is `if(nscan!=4 || termch!='\n') printf("Error\n");`.  This does not stop the call to the following `RecBSTInsert(&a,temp);`  Instead use `if(nscan!=4 || termch!='\n') { printf("Error\n"); break; }`.  Also suggest changing the format to `"%s%s ,%d%c"`.

Comment: none of the changes helped. By the way adding a comma to the format `%s %s, %d%c` or `%s%s ,%d%c` only makes the the _error_ appear

Comment: to the current code if i simply add this `printf("%d",i);` and `i++;` to count how many times the while runs , the entries are fine. I can not explain that

Answer (score 3):

fscanf:

> Upon successful completion, these functions shall return the number of
>   successfully matched and assigned input items.

fscanf does not return the input provided. That is why you are not seeing EOF like you are testing for.

See: [manpage for *scanf functions.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html)

---

To answer your other question, try looping through like this:

```
while (fscanf(infile, "%s %s %d%c, temp.name, temp.surname, &temp.code, &termch) == 4)
{
    //...
}
```

---

Edit again: I threw together a small program to simulate what I think you are doing. Here is my implementation, which takes from a file "testfile.txt" which looks like:

> Bill Person 1
>
> Bob Dog 2
>
> Andrew Cat 3

With only one newline between each line. It matches the pattern %s %s %d%c (where \n is the %c).

Program to use this file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct test {
    char name[64];
    char surname[64];
    int code;
};

int main()
{
    struct test temp;
    char endchar;
    FILE *infile = fopen("./testfile.txt", "r+"); // works with "r" as well, just a habit
    if (infile == NULL)
        return -1;
    while (fscanf(infile, "%s %s %d%c", temp.name, temp.surname, 
                  &temp.code, &endchar) == 4)
    {
        printf("Got one!\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, the `printf` exists in place of whatever logic you want to do on the current "temp" input.

Comment: thank you for your anwser but how should i try to stop the loop and check if the file has ended ?

Comment: Added an example to possibly help you out.

Comment: still,the last entry of the file is passed twice

Comment: I just tried this on my own with my own interpretation of the struct you are using. Please see my most recent edit. I have a dummy input file with three lines. My program outputs "Got one!\n" three times then exits.

Comment: my file is like this:

Bill Person ,1
Bob Dog ,2
Andrew Cat ,3

do you think due to the comma and my current code it cant work properly?

Comment: Then you are not scanning for the correct format string. That is `"%s %s %c%d%c"` because the comma is separated by spaces and is its own `char`. Try `while (fscanf(infile, "%s %s %c%d%c", temp.name, temp.surname, &killthecomma, &temp.code, &endchar) == 5)` where `killthecomma` is of type `char`.

Comment: @aglasser `"%s %s ,%d%c"` would be better.

Comment: You are right. I'm typing this all rather quickly while I'm working on a project of my own. I was in *format string* mode.

Comment: for some reason when i add `printf(%d",i);` and `i++` to check if the number of entries is ok, the last entry doesnt pass twice now

Comment: I tried it on my OS X box with that format string on the test file that I supplied, but added a comma before each integer. Assuming you really did mean `Bill Person ,1` with the comma immediately before the integer, it should work with my code and that format string. I tested it.

Comment: the comma and the integer have 1 whitespace difference

Comment: So it's `NAME SURNAME , CODE`? Space before the comma, space after the comma? Try `%s %s , %d%c`

Comment: posted the data of the file above

Comment: Then you need `%s %s, %d%c` with the comma next to the surname, then a space, then the int code. That is NOT what you told me in your comment above. `,%d` and `, %d` are entirely different. You also inputted the file all on one line. I assume this was a formatting issue and not how the actual file is laid out.

Comment: i am sorry for any haziness , i am trying to get used to this site.
But this `%s %s, %d%c' for some reason isnt working.
Also i copy pasted the file as it is.

Comment: Think about the format string. You are telling it to read a "STRING STRING, INTCHAR" until fscanf doesn't return 4. `Name Surname, Code\n`. If that is how each line in your file is laid out, the code works with that format string.

Comment: @aglasser your amended while loop `fscanf(infile, "%s %s ,%d%c", temp.name, temp.surname, &temp.code, &endchar) == 4` _should_ work.  OP's original post _should_ work.  There is something else we are assuming that is not correct.  I suspect OP's post and real problem differ.  The post is certainly lacking in declarations, etc.

Comment: @chux yep, I have a feeling there is more to this issue than we are seeing here.